# PHP regular expression to behave like mysql match

Tags: mysql, regex, preg-match, match, match-against

I need a PHP regular expression that will compare stings similar to mysql Match Against behaviour.

e.g:

```
string = "findmatches";
$pattern = 'fildcatches';
```

this pattern is supposed to match the string

Thanks a lot

Comment: MySQL's full-text searching is NOT a regex. You can probably simulate particular match-against scenarios with a specifc regex, but there won't be a general "does everything exactly the same" regex that replicates full-text searching.

Comment: This is not mysql's MATCH AGAINST behaviour either though

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression may not be the best solution for your needs, try instead the PHP construct similar_text() :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

The function returns the similarity between two strings in percentage and the number of matching chars.